# nHibernate Criteria queries produces duplicates using Paging

Tags: nhibernate

Version nHibernate 2.1

As can be seen from the vast array of similar questions - we're not alone in experiencing problems with paging generating duplicates.  We thought it was just happening with HQL queries but one of our clients has reported seeing it where the query is a Criteria query.

So far we've only seen it on the reporting side - where we tend to collect bits of information from various 'associated' entities and use the AliasToBeanTransformer to put it into a DTO (DataTransferObject):

.SetResultTransformer(new AliasToBeanResultTransformer(typeof(OurDTO)));

We're not new to nHibernate, but we're certainly not aware of so many of the subtleties of it, and as a result weren't aware of

new NHibernate.Transform.DistinctRootEntityResultTransformer()

which could potentially eliminate our duplicates, but I'm struggling to see how we could do this when it's not a mapped entity, i.e. a DTO.

We've tried creating a custom dialect which seems to have served some people well enough to be confident of consistent behaviour.

I realise there's no such thing as a silver bullet and context is always the kicker, but has anyone managed to come up with a solution for this?

The code we use to handle the collation of the pages is as follows:

```
        query.SetMaxResults(50);

        for (int i = 0; ; ++i)
        {
            query.SetFirstResult(i * 50);
            IList results = query.List();
            cumulativeResults.AddRange(results);
            OnRecordsLoaded(results.Count);
            if (results.Count < 50)
            { break; }
```

Many thanks for any input on this.
With kind regards
Colin

Answer (score -1):

NHibernate does not produce duplicates. The relational database does. And you cannot prevent that.

If your query involves a one - to -many join say you have customer and order tables and there is a  one to many relation between customers and orders and you query the customers filtering by order, you will get multiple multiple customers (of same identity)

The way to prevent it to use HashedSets in memory assuming you propery overrode Equals and GetHashCode for your entities which you should. If you put the result into HashedSet (from Iesi or .NET 4) they will elminate the duplicates.

That's one of the gotchas of ORMs.